# My own JButton preferred size is not working correctly?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

If I want to create my own custom `JButton` and i want to set the preferred size how do I go about doing this. I thought that it might be easy but when I get to it I have a dimension that I will be sending into my preferred size.

But then how do I set the correct **x**, **y**, **width**, and **height** values for my specific `JButton` component. It seems redundant to just call `setPreferredSize` again from in side of the same method?

This is the thing that I find odd about overriding a `JComponent`. I see how they are supposed to work with the `paintComponent(...)`.

I want my new button to have a preferred size (is this the default size) that is `20 x 20`.

I want to set this on any button were the size is not set by the constructor.

Also what methods should be overridden when creating a custom button?

```
class myButton extends JButton {
    public myButton(String s) {
        super(s);   
    }
    public void setPrefferedSize(Dimension d) {
        this.setBounds(x, y, width, height)
        setPreferredSize(d);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand - what is it about your button that you want to make custom? The default size and color?

Comment: Why does it seem redundant? If you want a button which has a smaller/larger, specific size or text it's logical to extend the button class and simply make those changes in it's constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Adding an `@Override` annotation to your `setPrefferedSize` method would have made clear that it should be called `setPreferredSize`.

Apart from that, the `getPreferredSize` and `setPreferredSize` methods have some special semantics in a `JComponent`. Quoting from the [JComponent#getPreferredSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize%28%29) documentation:

> If the preferredSize has been set to a non-null value just returns it. If the UI delegate's getPreferredSize method returns a non null value then return that; otherwise defer to the component's layout manager.

When setting the preferred size with `setPreferredSize`, everything is fine. (I'd **not** recommend to create a subclass of a component only to call some `set...` methods in the constructor, but I assume that you'll have some additional methods that will justify extending the class).

However, when overriding `getPreferredSize` of `JComponent`, one should try to preserve the semantics of this method. That means that you should rather override it like that

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    // If the preferred size was set manually, return this
    // size in order to be in line with the specification
    // that is described in the JavaDoc
    if (super.isPreferredSizeSet())
    {
        return super.getPreferredSize();
    }

    // Otherwise, return "your" preferred size. The
    // DEFAULT_WIDTH and DEFAULT_HEIGHT would be 20,20
    // in your case
    return new Dimension(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
}
```

(actually, one would have to first ask the UI for a preferred size, but this is probably not desired here)

Comment: If the super.getPreferredSize() is set than in this case you would just return the preferred size. How would that have gotten set?

Comment: @DougHauf I'm not sure whether I understood this question correctly, but when someone calls `setPreferredSize(dim)` from *outside*, then this preferred size will be stored (**IN** the `JComponent`), and the fact that it was manually set will be remembered - so that `isPreferredSizeSet()` will return `true` from then on, and this overridden method will just return the preferred size that was manually set and stored in the `JComponent`. Calling `setPreferredSize(null)` will restore "your" preferred size.

Answer (score 2):

call `super.setPreferredSize(d);` inside overridden `setPrefferedSize()` method otherwise it will result in `StackOverflowError` calling same method again and again.

---

Try with overridden `getPreferredSize()` method for your custom `JButton` class.

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(50, 20);
}
```

Comment: Were does the width and height originate from. There needs to be some variable that returns these variables correct.

Comment: I just copied from your code. you can pass 20,20 or any value. create some static final constants.

Answer (score 2):

Try overriding getMaximumSize and getMinimumSize. Which value is used and how they are used depends on the layout (and its implementation). Setting all three (min, max, preferred) should get you a definite size if the layout doesn't misbehave.

Answer (score 1):

It's really very simple.

```
public class MyButton extends JButton {

    public MyButton(String s) {
        super(s);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 14));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setFont( new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 10));
        this.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

It's not redundant to use the methods to set something predefined, it's how your supposed to do it. What would be redundant would be doing this on 24+ buttons in your program, cluttering your guy constructor up with code it doesn't need to have.

Comment: I would also add that it is, in general, not the components job to decide its bounds, but rather of the layout manager. As such, calling setBounds is actually detrimental and will make these buttons break in some configuration.

Comment: Also, seems this is the only answer that leaves room to change the size while leaving other defaults untouched.

Comment: What i the paintComponent was listed in this configuration. Also if this was a custom JComponent what methods should be included?

Comment: Forgot one thing. I do know that there are more methods that are used in custom components that are used outside of the construtors. What methods should be included in any custom JComponent object.  class myComponent() extends JComponenet { .... }