# how to set the size of JPanel in java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, preferredsize

I have a JPanel in my java code and I want to set its size, I have used JPanel.setSize(500,500); and JPanel.setSize(new Dimension(500,500)); but both are not working. Please tell how I can set the size of JPanel?

Answer (score 6):

Most Swing layout managers respect a component's preferredSize and not its size. You could call `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500))`, but this can be overridden later in your code, and can lead to an inflexible GUI. Better to override the JPanel's `getPreferredSize()` method and return a calculated Dimension that works best in all situations.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.*;

public class PrefSizePanel extends JPanel {

   private static final int PREF_W = 500;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;

   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      // update as per Marco:
      if (super.isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   // just for fun
   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.red, 20, 20, Color.blue, true));
      g2.fillOval(0, 0, 2 * getWidth(), 2 * getHeight());
   }

   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      PrefSizePanel paintEg = new PrefSizePanel();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("PrefSizePanel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(paintEg);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

---

Which displays as

[image]

Comment: The hint to override `getPreferredSize` is given rather frequently. However, I think that in an overridden version of this method, the `isPreferredSizeSet` property should be queried, because otherwise, the method will simply not behave according to the specification: When the preferred size was set explicitly, then this preferred size should be returned, regardless of the components "inherent" preferred size. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23503703/3182664

Comment: @Marco13: thank you for your info and link, 1+. I've edited my answer's sample code accordingly.